# How can I set an Admin/Superuser role to have complete access using Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security

I want to limit access to directories based on roles, e.g.,:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/foo/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_FOO')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/bar/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_BAR')"/>
```

But I also want a superuser role that can access everything, e.g., :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERUSER')"/>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this other than using hasAnyRole, throughout? e.g.,

```
<!-- This seems ugly, with all the repeated references. OTOH, it's explicit -->
<intercept-url pattern="/foo/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_FOO', 'ROLE_SUPERUSER')"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/bar/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_BAR') or hasRole('ROLE_SUPERUSER')"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a case for [`RoleHierarchy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchy.html).

Though I can't find a good way how to configure it. Perhaps this rough approach would work:

```
public class RoleHierarchyInjectionBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {        
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (bean instanceof DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) {
            ((DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setRoleHierarchy(...);
        }
        return bean;
    }     
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In  [this article](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/01/02/spring-security-customization-part-2-adjusting-secured-session-in-real-time/) there is a solution to a similar problem. You can ignore the part about JMX, what matters to you is the talk about `AccessDecisionManager` and `AccessDecisionVoter`. The idea is to register a custom `AccessDecisionVoter` that implements the `if (superuser) grant access;`logic.